# Simulating a space engine

Tags: matlab, ode

I want to simulate the motion of a space engine from low Earth's orbit with initial conditions emulating the initial thrust.

I did all the code, but when I plot the **ODE** solution all I have is a point, I just don’t know where I am wrong.

I put the code down here, it is not very complicated, I just had to solve the motion equations.

```matlab
function sol = orbital_motion()
% Define the function that returns the derivative of the state vector
    function dydt = ode(t, y)
        % Extract the state variables
        X = y(1);
        Y = y(2);
        Z = y(3);
        Xdot = y(4);
        Ydot = y(5);
        Zdot = y(6);
     
        Xm = 278,481; Ym = 378,481; Zm = 268,481;
        Xs = 147098,074 ; Ys = 696,166 ; Zs = 1515,776 ;
        mu_e = 3.986135e14; %sets the gravitational parameter for the Earth.
        mu_m = 4.89820e12;%sets the gravitational parameter for the Moon.
        mu_s = 1.3253e20;%sets the gravitational parameter for the Sun.
        a = 6.37826e6; %the equatorial radius of the Earth.
        J = 1.6246e-3;%sets the Earth's second dynamic form factor.
        % Calculate the distances and other parameters
        r = sqrt(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2);
        rm = sqrt(Xm^2 + Ym^2 + Zm^2);
        delta_m = sqrt((X - Xm)^2 + (Y - Ym)^2 + (Z - Zm)^2);
        delta_s = sqrt((X - Xs)^2 + (Y - Ys)^2 + (Z - Zs)^2);
        Y_s = Ys;
        Z_s = Zs;
        % Calculate the derivatives
        X2dot = -((mu_e*Y)/r^3) * (1 + (J*(a/r)^2)*(1 - 5*Z^2/r^2)) ...
            - (mu_m*(X - Xm)/delta_m^3) ...
            - (mu_m*Xm/rm^3) ...
            - (mu_s*(X - Xs)/delta_s^3) ...
            - (mu_s*Xs/r^3);
        Y2dot = -((mu_e*Y)/r^3) * (1 + (J*(a/r)^2)*(1 - 5*Z^2/r^2)) ...
            - (mu_m*(Y - Ym)/delta_m^3) ...
            - (mu_m*Ym/rm^3) ...
            - (mu_s*(Y - Y_s)/delta_s^3) ...
            - (mu_s*Ys/r^3);
        Z2dot = -((mu_e*Z)/r^3) * (1 + (J*(a/r)^2)*(3 - 5*Z^2/r^2)) ...
            - (mu_m*(Z - Zm)/delta_m^3) ...
            - (mu_m*Zm/rm^3) ...
            - (mu_s*(Z - Z_s)/delta_s^3) ...
            - (mu_s*Zs/r^3);
     
        % Return the derivative vector
        dydt = [Xdot; Ydot; Zdot; X2dot; Y2dot; Z2dot];
    end

% Set the initial conditions
X0 = 0;
Y0 = 0;
Z0 = 0;
Xdot0 = 11436.6;
Ydot0 = 0;
Zdot0 = 0;
y0 = [X0; Y0; Z0; Xdot0; Ydot0; Zdot0];

% Define the time span
tf = 20;
tspan = [0, tf];

% Call ODE45
%options = odeset('RelTol', 1e-8, 'AbsTol
# [t,y] = ode45(@ode,[0 20],y0);
plot(t,y(:,1),'-o',t,y(:,2),'-o',t,y(:,3),'-o')
title('Solution of the Motion Equation with gODE45');
end**your text**
```

Comment: What are `X,Y,Z`, the coordinates relative to the center of Earth or to Sun? You mix both i the terms `mu_s*Xs/r^3`? // You would greatly simplify your code of you worked with 3-vectors. // Did you translate the gravity constants from meter to kilometer? // Do you start your rocket at the center of Earth?

Comment: Good programming practice would be to have comments off to the side indicating the units used in every single numeric constant in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use commas in numeric constants:

```
Xm = 278,481; Ym = 378,481; Zm = 268,481;
Xs = 147098,074 ; Ys = 696,166 ; Zs = 1515,776 ;
```

If they are supposed to be decimal points, use periods:

```
Xm = 278.481; Ym = 378.481; Zm = 268.481;
Xs = 147098.074 ; Ys = 696.166 ; Zs = 1515.776 ;
```

Otherwise, just eliminate them:

```
Xm = 278481; Ym = 378481; Zm = 268481;
Xs = 147098074 ; Ys = 696166 ; Zs = 1515776 ;
```